# JavaFX2 TreeItem not showing when added to TreeView

Tags: treeview, javafx-2, javafx

I've got a TreeView. I've added context menus to the items in the tree and I react to a menu selection by adding a node. For some reason, the first time I click on the context menu, the menu does not disappear and the TreeView UI is not updated. If I click again the context menu disappear and 2 items are added to the tree. If I go to the context menu again and click it adds 1 item normally every subsequent time. Any advice?

I use TreeItem.getChildren().add() to add sub-TreeItems. Here is the code that creates the TreeCell factory (which creates the context menu.

```
public NodeTreeView(NodeView rootNodeView) {
    setRoot(rootNodeView);
    setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
            return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl();
        }
    });
    getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(this);
}

@Override
public void changed(
        ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<String>> ov,
        TreeItem<String> deselectedTreeItem,
        TreeItem<String> selectedTreeItem) {
    NodeView nodeView = null;

    nodeView = (NodeView) selectedTreeItem;
    System.out.println("Display properties for " + nodeView.getController().getType());
}

private final class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<String> {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            NodeMenuController nodeMenuController = null;

            nodeMenuController = new NodeMenuController(getController());
            setText(getString());
            setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
            setContextMenu(nodeMenuController.getView());
    }
```

Finally, here's how the menu items are built:

```
public class NodeMenuController {

private NodeController nodeController;

public NodeMenuController(NodeController controller) {
    this.nodeController = controller;
}

public ContextMenu getView() {
    ContextMenu contextMenu = null;

    contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    if (ChildMap.hasAllowedChildren(nodeController.getType())) {
        contextMenu.getItems().add(getAddChildMenuItem());
    }
    return contextMenu;
}

private MenuItem getAddChildMenuItem() {
    Menu         menu             = null;
    List<String> allowedChildList = null;

    menu = new Menu("+ Child");
    allowedChildList = ChildMap.get(nodeController.getType());
    for (final String allowedChildType : allowedChildList) {
        MenuItem menuItem = null;

        menuItem = new MenuItem(allowedChildType);
        menuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event t) {
                NodeController newNodeController = null;

                newNodeController = new NodeController(new NodeModel(allowedChildType));
                nodeController.add(newNodeController);
            }
        });
        menu.getItems().add(menuItem);
    }
    return menu;
}
}
```

Comment: can u provide `NodeMenuController` code?

Comment: I added the whole NodeMenuController class. If necessary I can strip everything away to get simplified example that demonstrates the problem. I just thought someone might have an answer with out a working example.

Comment: can't find anything wrong.You may try to wrap new node creation into `Platform.runLater()` to avoid looped creation of context menu for new item from context menu handler

Comment: Did it work for you? Note, if yes it may mean that you have a threading problem somewhere in your code .

Comment: Sorry, didn't try yet. Probably won't be able to until Monday. I'll let you know... thanks.

Comment: I wrapped my handler in Platform.runLater(), but it didn't help. When I ran it though, I noticed for the first time that it was throwing a NullPointerException (the first time a node is added, it looks like my selection handler is called w/ the treeitem, then called again w/ null for some reason, which I wasn't handling). Anyway NPE fixed and I no longer have the problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had a NullPointerException in the selection handler that I hadn't noticed. If anyone has this problem, that's one thing to check.